# Toggle hidden divs by clicking on navigation?

Tags: jquery

How do I toggle hidden divs by clicking on nav anchors?

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/4rfYB/1/

I have written it the very long way round by naming each id individually, however there must be a shorter way of writing this?

```
$('#link1').click(function() {
    $('#1').show()
    $('#2, #3').hide()
})
$('#link2').click(function() {
    $('#2').show()
    $('#1, #3').hide()
})
    $('#link3').click(function() {
    $('#3').show()
    $('#2, #1').hide()
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/4rfYB/2/

```
$('nav a').click(function() {
  $('.navLinks').hide();                 // Hide all
  $(this.getAttribute('href')).show();   // Show HREF/to/ID one
});
```

so you just need to get the `href` of your anchor (i.e. `#1`) and target the jQuery `$()` element ID represented by that href value :)

If you want a **oneliner**: http://jsfiddle.net/4rfYB/5/

```
$('.navLinks').hide().filter(this.getAttribute('href')).show();
```

You can also use a less flexible way using `.eq()` and `.index()` http://jsfiddle.net/4rfYB/7/

```
$('.navLinks').hide().eq( $(this).index() ).show();
```

<sub>Note that **numeric ID** are only valid in **HTML5**!</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) attribute along with modified HTML

```
<nav>
     <a id="link1" class="link" href="#1" data-id="1">1</a>
     <a id="link2" class="link" href="#2" data-id="2">2</a>
     <a id="link3" class="link" href="#3" data-id="3">3</a>
</nav>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');  
    $(".navLinks").hide();
    $("#"+id).show();
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4rfYB/4/)

Answer (score 1):

without using nums 1,2,3

you could define it dynamically.

```
$('nav a').click(function() {
  $('.navLinks').hide();
  var index = $('nav a').index(this);
  $('.navLinks').eq(index).show();
})
```

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rtGk6/1/

Comment: Don't use selectors overhead `$($())` rather this concept: http://jsfiddle.net/4rfYB/9/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here's a fiddle for your question. This way you can change the href to any particular link you want. [jsfiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/4rfYB/6/)

```
$('.links').click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-').pop();
$('.navLinks').hide();
$('#'+id).show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery selector based on nav > a to easily reference that dom element. Using jQuery and $(this), which refers to the anchor you just clicked:

```
<div class="nav">
    <nav>
       <a id="link1" href="#1">1</a>
       <a id="link2" href="#2">2</a>
       <a id="link3" href="#3">3</a>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="1" class="navLinks"> content 1 </div>
<div id="2" class="navLinks"> content 2 </div>
<div id="3" class="navLinks"> content 3 </div>
```

Then use this javascript:

```
jQuery("nav a").click(function(){
    jQuery(".navLinks").hide();
    var num = jQuery(this).attr("id").replace("link","");
    jQuery("#"+num).show()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3aAg/

Answer (score 0):

You seems new to jQuery and wonna learn so I will give you few pointers:

Use [Custom Data Attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) (data-*)  to store custom variables, instead of using the `href`.

To initially hide elements write a inline `style='display:none'`. **CSS** and **JS** will be loaded with some **delay** and may create ugly looking effects.

jQuery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will hide / show the components if it is visible / hidden acrodingly.

Here is an example how to solve your problem in a bit more clean, it is **NOT** the most efficient way but is easy to understand learn from.

[fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rfYB/11/)

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
    <nav>
       <a href="#" data-id="1">1</a>
       <a href="#" data-id="2">2</a>
       <a href="#" data-id="3">3</a>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="1" class="navLinks" style='display:none'> content 1 </div>
<div id="2" class="navLinks" style='display:none'> content 2 </div>
<div id="3" class="navLinks" style='display:none'> content 3 </div>
```

JS

```
$('nav a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stop the normal link click event.
    var divId = $(this).attr('data-id'); //get the target Div ID.
    $('#'+divId).toggle(); //toggle will hide/show the div properly
});
```